# Client Not loading Webpage

Tags: http, tcp

Setup

180.87.13.77 ===Router=========GRE TUNNEL=========ROUTER=====Internet===Webserver

The client .77 cannot open few web sites.
We did a packet capture and noticed in all the TCP sessions
after HTTP GET is requested, Server is Sending RST/ACK
THis terminate the session.
No idea on what is happening.[Wireshark Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkXeC.png)

Comment: This is probably a deep inspection firewall resetting the connection after having a look at the GET request.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We are accessing this website in Shanghai using Hongkong Public IP via VPN Tunnel..Not all servers are rejecting the connections. Only few websites..Is there way the server is predicting the geo location not based on IP address and then rejecting it ?

Comment: The  server might restrict access based on a variety of features, including IP address,  known VPN endpoint, TOR node etc.